# How to restore the string in AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Here is my code.
I want my AutoCompleteTextView to contain the string which was entered before clicking the go_button.
my actv.setText is not working as expected.

```
final AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.searchAutoCompleteTextView_feed);

        Button go_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.goButton_feed);

        go_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                search_string = actv.getText().toString();

                actv.setText(search_string);

                Intent intent = new Intent(FeedListViewActivity.this, SearchActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Log.d("onClick", search_string);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am setting the text in FeedListViewActivity, but what i see is SearchActivity. should set the text in SearchActivity.